# How does LightDM treat PAM?

Tags: lightdm, pam

I use XFCE as my desktop, and I wanna know how LightDM works with PAM.

1. when I use normal kernel arguments, LightDM starts and then XFCE is started by LightDM.
2. When I add "text" to kernel parameter, it boots to virtual terminal 1, and I log in with a normal user, say, testuser. Then I type "startxfce4" to start xfce. Note, this is done with testuser account, so the process all belong to testuser. Then XFCE desktop shows. But I cannot reboot/shutdown using the desktop buttons, and cannot edit network connection using NetworkManager nm-connection-editor, actuallyh it's grayed out.

So I think LightDM must do something to authenticate testuser to have privilege rights, perhaps with PAM, or keyring, or polkit? I don't quite understand such thing...

Would anyone do me a favor to give a detailed and pragramming explanation of this? I'm a programmer who's interested in know every aspects of this...

Many thanks!

EDIT: a subsequent question is, how to achieve the same privilege/environment using startxfce4 in virtual terminal, compared with start xfce by LightDM?